# How to design an index/query to avoid filesort in a simple MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, filesort

I have a table `entrytable`, that has the colums `datum`, `username`, `status`, `status_spam_user`, `status_spam_system` and `text`.

I want to select the content of the column text, from rows that have certain values for `username`, `status`, `status_spam_user`, `status_spam_system`. Since this can result in a long list of entries (>30'000) I want to limit the number of matching rows. Before I to that, the matching rows should be ordered by the column `datum`.

```
SELECT text
FROM entrytable
WHERE user = 'username' &&
`status` = '1' && (
    `status_spam_user` = 'no_spam'
    || (
        `status_spam_user` = 'neutral' &&
        `status_spam_system` = 'neutral'
    )
)
ORDER BY datum DESC
LIMIT 6430 , 10
```

I added two indices to the table:

- index_datum (datum)
- index_status_mit_spam (user, status, status_spam_user, status_spam_system)

For this query the index `index_status_mit_spam` is used. Since the index does not contain information of the column `datum`, the sorting has to be does separately (i.e. filesort). Is it possible to design my query/index in a way, that it is useful for the `WHERE` as well as for `ORDER BY`?

Comment: please post the explain plan..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on `(user, status, datum)`
index on status_spam_user/status_spam_system can't be used because of the OR condition (it is used up to the status part), and all previous parts of the index have to be used before the order by part can be satisfied with an index